# Springboot server-side chart creation

Tags: java, spring-boot, charts, scriptengine, spring-thymeleaf

I want to create Google Charts at server-end. I found some plugins like -
[GWT Tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/gwt-charts), but I did not find it helpful because we need client-side interaction here. I need something using which I can create charts at server end so that I can store these charts images without requiring user to interact. I also found one more plugin - [Charts4j](https://code.google.com/archive/p/charts4j/), but I did not find any helpful examples or tutorial for this plugin.

`Update`-
Using `Thymeleaf`, I was able to load the HTML file to backend and was able to convert the HTML as PDF using [HTMLToPDF](https://github.com/wooio/htmltopdf-java) plugin. The HTML is working beautifully fine. The PDF is getting generated. Now only issue left is that the javascript from HTML is not getting evaluated. Any solution for this?

`Another Update` -

When I find a solution I find another obstacle. I was able to execute the script using [ScripEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html), but ScriptEngine did not find `document`. Then I used [Java Jsoup's Document](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html), sent the object to ScriptEngine, but again Jsoup's Document has different methods than Javascript's document.

Comment: Not sure what your question has to do with Spring Boot but, what you are referring to are javascript (which usually is needed for charts). So, if you want the chart to be created server side, you would need to look at something like NodeJS or NextJs or NuxtJS

Comment: I don't want any client side interaction. My server is `Spring Boot based application`. I want to configure charts at the server end, convert these chart objects to images and send them via mail. I have a scheduler that will run my API on scheduled time. This API will take the chart related data stored in DB and I need to make use of the data for configuring charts. To be clear, `no user interaction`.

Comment: What came to my mind was, sending the data to a model view, configuring charts in this view using `Javascript`, and then hitting my another API, sending this configured HTML back to server. But that won't work unless the view is loaded on browser.

Comment: So, as I understand it, you need the chart as a picture file to include in your e-mail, correct? Something like JFreeChart might do the trick

Comment: JFreeChart does not generate good UI. Also limited charts and options. I was thinking like some thymeleaf scenario where I can read the template, add the required values and get the HTML after configuring charts using javascript.

Comment: These options would require javascript running in a browser or a node environment. I don't think it is possible in Spring Boot per se. Calling an node JS API from Spring Boot might do the trick though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I solved my issue using `Thymeleaf`, `Selenium` and `IText HTML2PDF`. I followed given steps -

I added below dependencies to my POM -

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, I resolved my HTML template containing javascript using ThymeleafResolver -

```
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/<My folder name in resources>/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");

    return templateResolver;
}

public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(messageSource());
    return templateEngine;
}
```

And in my code I used -

```
Context ctx = new Context();
String html = templateEngine.process(<My HTML file name>, ctx);
```

This resolved my HTML. Now, about javascript, I referred this - [Evaludate JS](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/evaluating-js-with-pdfhtml), and my issue was resolved.

Thank you.